# Is it possible to set the final value of a capture group?

Tags: c, pcre, capture-group

I have a very specific use case where a system is using REs to extract data and in this case I would prefer to not return the matched value but an arbitrary value. This would be more convenient than updating the underlying software.

I was wondering if this was achievable by somehow setting the value of a capture group without affecting the matching behavior. I thought maybe something like a "constant" callout that would do something like an `(?(*ACCEPT))` and return whatever it is passed as text.

If group `1` matches, then return `OK` else `NOT OK`:

```
(.*)(?(1)(?CC"OK")|(?CC"NOT OK"))
```

*(`CC` is the magic I need)*

I've been reading [this](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html) and [this](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html) but haven't found anything of the sort.

Comment: Curious requirement.  I'm fairly sure the answer is "No", but I'm puzzled about how you'd be modifying the code using the REs to use the extension yet not need to know what's going on.  It feels a bit like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) — though not as definitively XY-ish as many.  I think there ought to be another way to handle it, but I'm not sure since you haven't illustrated with actual code what you need.  (Think MCVE — [MCVE]!)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Let me rephrase. For the purposes here, assume the code is buried somewhere dark. The program consumes a string, and a regular expression (libpcre) and outputs the values of the expression's capture groups matched on the data. Normally, whatever is in the capture group is fine. For the use case here, I want to replace or add a capture group with a predetermined value that is not present in the data and that must not have a effect on the behavior of the rest of the expression. (ie, With "abc" =~ /(abc)/, I want $1=="0", instead of $1=="abc")

Comment: The extra information clarifies — but would be best put into the question.  I still think the answer is "No".  AFAIK, not even Perl manages that with pure match regexes, though it would get close with the `x` modifier for the replacement part of a `s///` expression.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no PCRE feature implemented to define a default value or whatsoever for a capturing group. You are in need of a programming language.

Comment: Have you tried the [https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2callout.html](callout) facility?  This would allow you to set variables (excluding the internal state of PCRE) to whatever you want.